# Binario para texto

Tags: lua

Estou tentando ler um valor binário de uma tabela, mas não consigo pegar o que quero.
Em lua, existe alguma maneira de converter conteúdo binário para texto?
Banco de dados mysql.
Estou tentando o seguinte comando:

```
"SELECT `itemtype`, `count`, `attributes` FROM `player_depotitems` WHERE `player_id` = 1405;"
```

Mas em attributes, em string, retorna algo como

```
€
```

Comment: Coloca o código do que você já fez ou tente [edit] sua pergunta para dar mais detalhes sobre o que deseja. Veja se isto te ajuda http://codea.io/talk/discussion/1130/bstring-lua-a-utility-to-convert-binary-file-to-lua-strings/p1

Comment: Na verdade não fiz nada, não tenho ideia de como começar.

Comment: Bigown, obrigado, mas não consegui tirar nada.
É assim, no database, diz que o item é [BLOB], isso é binário, certo? Quero ler isso.

Comment: Já melhorou, já sabemos que você quer ler um banco de dados. Qual banco está usando? Seria interessante [edit] a pergunta para colocar essa informação e como está a tabela. Veja estas bibliotecas http://lua-users.org/wiki/DatabaseAccess E veja exemplos http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_database_access.htm

Comment: Já tenho a biblioteca. Pelo que li, blob guarda o dados em forma de tabela binária.

Comment: Aí talvez nem seja um problema para resolver na linguagem. O problema é você entender o que tem neste campo `attributes`. Este símbolo quer dizer alguma coisa. Provavelmente existe alguma documentação sobre o conteúdo deste campo. A *string* tem uma informação codificada de alguma forma. Precisa entender como ela é e como (se se dá para) descodificá-la, ou seja precisa transformar em algo mais compreensível. Talvez nem seja, talvez nem precise. Talvez seja só uma questão de saber o que cada informação armazenada signifique. Informe mais sobre este campo.

Comment: Bom, este campo armazena basicamente texto.